# Realm + Retrofit + RxJava: Concat and SubscribeOn

Tags: realm, retrofit, rx-java, concatenation

I am having an issue while using the RxJava concat operator. I have two observables, the first emits results from a server database and the other one emits results from the local database, and then I concat the :

```
// Uses a Realm in the UI thread
Observable<MyResult> remoteObservable = mRemoteDataSource.find(tId);

// Uses Retrofit
Observable<MyResult> localObservable = mLocalDataSource.find(tId);

Observable.concat(localObservable, remoteObservable)
    .doOnNext(result -> /* Do my stuff */)
    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
    .doOnError(throwable -> throwable.printStackTrace())
    .subscribe()
```

So this causes me problem, since I am not using `subscribeOn()` the concatenated observable is running on `AndroidScheduler.MainThread()` and this does not run the remote and it launches a `NetworkOnMainThreadException`.

If I implement a `subscribeOn(Schedulers.computation())` I get `Realm access from incorrect thread. Realm objects can only be accessed on the thread they were created` since of course the Observable is not running on the thread the Realm instance does exist.

I have searched in other questions and I have not gotten anything useful, I have checked the example made by realm: https://github.com/realm/realm-java/blob/master/examples/rxJavaExample/src/main/java/io/realm/examples/rxjava/retrofit/RetrofitExample.java but strangely I see that the retrofit observable is subscribed on nothing and it works.

Why does it work on the sample and in my code I cannot do the same? Any suggestion?

Comment: ...is it really your `local` observable that uses Retrofit?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you should use `subscribeOn()` in the right places.

```
// Uses a Realm in the UI thread
Observable<MyResult> realmObservable = mRealmDataSource.find(tId).subscribeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread());

// Uses Retrofit
Observable<MyResult> retrofitObservable = mRetrofitDataSource.find(tId).subscribeOn(Subscribers.io());

Observable.concat(realmObservable, retrofitObservable)
    .doOnNext(result -> /* Do my stuff */)
    .subscribeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
    .doOnError(throwable -> throwable.printStackTrace())
    .subscribe()
```

See if it fixes your issue.

Comment: Thanks for that, I suppossed it too and tried it but the behavior of my app turned strange and only the first observable in the concat worked. I am sure I was doing something else but I already changed my original implementation. Thank you anyways.

Answer (score 2):

You can concat your local and remote observables like below:

```
// Uses a Realm in the UI thread
Observable<MyResult> remoteObservable = mRemoteDataSource.find(tId);

// Uses Retrofit
Observable<MyResult> localObservable = mLocalDataSource.find(tId);

Observable.concat(localObservable, remoteObservable).first()
                .map(new Func1<MyResult, MyResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public myResult call(MyResult result) {
                        if (result == null) {
                            throw new IllegalArgumentException();
                        }
                        return result;
                    }
                });
```

And subscribe like below:

```
CompositeSubscription mCompositeSubscription = new CompositeSubscription();
final Subscription subscription = mRepo.find(tId
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribe(new Observer<MyResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCompleted() {
                        // Completed
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError(Throwable e) {
                        // onError
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onNext(MyResult result) {
                        //onSuccess
                    }
                });
mCompositeSubscription.add(subscription);
```

You can check this repo for RxJava + Retrofit + Realm
https://github.com/savepopulation/wikilight

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `subscribeOn` at `mRealmDataSource.find(tId).subscribeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())`
like said : https://stackoverflow.com/a/39304891/2425851

You can use `Observable.defer`
for example:

```
class RealmDataSource{
fun find(id: String): Observable<MyResult> {
// Default pattern for loading data on a background thread
return Observable.defer{
                val realm = Realm.getInstance()

                val query = realm
                    .where(MyResult::class.java)

                val flowable =
                    if (realm.isAutoRefresh) {
                        query
                            .findAllAsync()
                            .asFlowable()
                            .filter(RealmResults::isLoaded)
                    } else {
                        Flowable.just(query.findAll())
                    }

                return@defer flowable
                    .toObservable()
            }
}
```

Then usage will be without `subscribeOn`

```
// Uses a Realm
Observable<MyResult> realmObservable = mRealmDataSource.find(tId);

// Uses Retrofit
Observable<MyResult> remoteObservable = mRemoteDataSource.find(tId);
```

For more info see https://realm.io/blog/realm-java-0-87-0/